After installing QGIS 3.36.1 -> 3.36.2 Go2streetview window looks black
After installing a new version of QGIS (3.36.2) Go2streetview screen becomes black.
I also have an old version. Here (same streetview settings/API) the problems do not occur.

May be related to https://github.com/enricofer/go2streetview/issues/92
